# Selecting the link from multiple search results in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am writing the test code using java selenium web driver, 
I want to search for "Honey rose varghese" and when the result is available, from this result I want to click the Filmography link available on the result page.

```
public class ByPartialLink {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
    WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
    searchbox.sendKeys("Honey rose varghese");
    searchbox.submit();
    Thread.sleep(3000);     
    List<WebElement> search =  driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Filmography"));
    System.out.println(search.size());
}

}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by selecting the link from multiple search results? Are there multiple links with the test 'Filmography'? Would you want to select the first link displayed in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me and returned 1. I just searched for the full link text instead of partial. Using a `Thread.sleep()` isn't a best practice. Try the `WebDriverWait` below for better, more consistent results.

```
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
searchbox.sendKeys("Honey rose varghese");
searchbox.submit();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("resultStats")));
// Thread.sleep(3000);
List<WebElement> search = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Filmography"));
System.out.println(search.size());
```

---

EDIT 1: after feedback

If you want to click the first Filmography link, there are a couple ways to do this...

1) Maybe you want to count the number of links to make sure there's only one, etc. You could still use the code above but click the first element.

```
List<WebElement> search = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Filmography"));
search.get(0).click();
```

2) If you always want to click the first link or are confident that there will ever only be one link you can just use `.findElement()` to return only the first element and click it.

```
WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Filmography"));
search.click();
```

or a one-liner...

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Filmography")).click();
```

Best practice in a case like this (where there might be none or more than one search result) would be to return the collection and make sure there is at least one.

```
List<WebElement> search = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Filmography"));
if (!search.isEmpty())
{
    search.get(0).click();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info of WebDriverWait class. I wanted to know, when the search result returns 1, how can I click the link and open that filmography link. when I tried, I got error as Element Not found.

Comment: I would recommend waiting to accept an answer after getting a solution, just in case other people give solutions that might work for people that find the question further on.

Comment: @Iridann that's not how SO works. He should accept the answer that best fits *his* question... not based on what other people might find useful later (I'm not sure how he's supposed to know that anyway). Others can provide alternate answers even after he accepts an answer. That said, if the questioner doesn't feel that he's found a good answer (s)he is free to wait longer.

Comment: @JeffC It's actually often mentioned in Meta that it is recommended. Aside from that your answer doesnt actually answer the question, so it shouldnt have been accepted regardless.

Comment: @Iridann his original code didn't include a `.click()` attempt. I assumed from this, maybe wrongly, that his problem was a timing issue so I set about to solve that. Once that was solved, it seemed to me that the `.click()` on the obtained element would be a simple thing. I have edited my answer to show this also because you are correct, I technically didn't actually answer the question asked.